# Filter data quarterly using LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am having list of Items.

```
class Item{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Getting list of quarters along with years like Q1 2012, Q2 2013

I need to filter list of  based on quarter list.
I just need list of Item Names which are having specified quarter list.

Comment: You mean you want `List<List<Item>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model the quarter as a struct:

```
public struct Quarter
{
    public Quarter(int year, int quarterIndex)
    {
        Year = year;
        QuarterIndex = quarterIndex;
    }

    public static Quarter FromDate(DateTime date)
    {
        return new Quarter(date.Year, 1 + (date.Month - 1)/3);
    }

    public int Year;
    public int QuarterIndex;
}
```

Then, simply set a target list of quarters and do the filtering with LINQ (the code assumes your existing collection of items is called `items`):

```
var targetQuarters = new[]
{
    new Quarter(2012, 1),
    new Quarter(2013, 1)
};

var itemsInTargetQuarters = 
    items.Where(i => targetQuarters.Contains(Quarter.FromDate(i.CreatedDate)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: How do you go from quarter to date, quarter beginning date or end date

Comment: @transformer I don't go from quarter to date. It's the other way around.

Comment: yes, I see that. I was asking how to get the first and lastdates of the quarter i.e. for any given  date or quarter. But I just figured it out! :) I also see you're querying on quarters, how can we apply this linq to a query on a list of say products or timecards

Answer (score 2):

Like Nikhil asked, I'm not sure what result you are looking for, but here are some suggestions.  Do either of these lists give what you need?  itemsByQuarter has each item grouped in a list based on quarter.  secondQuarterItemNames is just a list of the names of items in Q2.  Hope this helps you think on the right path.

```
class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static int QuarterFromMonth(int month)
    {
        return (month-1) / 3 + 1;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Item[] items = 
        { 
            new Item {Id = 1, CreatedDate = new DateTime(2014, 4, 1), Name = "AprilItem"},
            new Item {Id = 1, CreatedDate = new DateTime(2014, 7, 1), Name = "JulyItem"},
            new Item {Id = 1, CreatedDate = new DateTime(2014, 10, 1), Name = "OctoberItem"},
        };

        var itemsByQuarter = items.GroupBy(i => QuarterFromMonth(i.CreatedDate.Month));
        var secondQuarterItemNames = items.Where(i => QuarterFromMonth(i.CreatedDate.Month) == 2).Select(i => i.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh, w0lf posted as i was typing.  our answers look similar.

Comment: As a suggestion: Maybe making Quarter a Property  in the Item-class? Would look cleaner imo

Comment: Christian: or make a subclass of DateTime that has a Quarter Property :)